# How to change position of last row in mysql to first row?

Tags: mysql

my sql query is

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM <DB> GROUP BY InputTime ORDER BY InputTime) A GROUP BY HOUR(InputTime) WITH ROLLUP;
```

And the result is

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|    62 |
|   200 |
|    10 |
|   272 |
+-------+
```

Last row is the sum of previous values. How to make last row to first row like this?

```
+-------+
| count |
+-------+
|   272 |
|    62 |
|   200 |
|    10 |
+-------+
```

Comment: What about ordering it `DESC`?

Comment: And put the OrderBy at the end of the query, not in the middle of it

Comment: Your query definitely isn't that because that query has a syntax error and won't run

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM (SELECT InputTime FROM DBname where InputTime>= '2021-07-07' AND InputTime <='2021-07-07 23:56:59' GROUP BY InputTime) A GROUP BY HOUR(InputTime) WITH ROLLUP;

This is my actual query

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT IFNULL(hours,'Total'), count
FROM
(SELECT HOUR(InputTime) hours, COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM DBname where InputTime>= '2021-07-07' AND InputTime <='2021-07-07 23:56:59' GROUP BY HOUR(InputTime) WITH ROLLUP) V
ORDER BY hours ASC;
```

Since the `ROLLUP` returned `NULL` for `hours` column in the subquery, the `ORDER BY hours` in the outer query will put it on top.  *"[.. In MySQL NULL values are considered lower than any non-NULL value, therefore, NULL values appear first when the order is ASC (ascending), and ordered last when the order is DESC (descending) ..](https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-order-null-values-first-or-last-in-mysql) "*

[Demo fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v3hB6Krrmwz88mhcdPi6i6/0)

Answer (score 0):

I'd select the hour(inputtime) too, and order by it. The roll up line will have a null for it and nulls sort first.